# Segmentation fault when using pthread_join in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pthreads

So, I was working on some of my homework and I'm stuck on this seg. fault I got when trying to call pthread_join.

I have tried different solutions including creating a void pointer to send to the pthread_join call.

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NTHREADS 5
#define NVALORES 1000
#define NUMBER_PROCURADO 890

void * run(void *arg);
void fillVector();
int vetor[NVALORES];

int main(){

    int i, vetor2[NTHREADS];
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    fillVector();
    for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++){
        vetor2[i]=i;
        threads[i]= pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, run, &vetor2[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

void * run(void * arg){
    int *pos = (int *) arg;

    int i;
    for (i = NVALORES/NTHREADS*(*pos); i < NVALORES/NTHREADS*((*pos)+1); i++){
        if(vetor[i]==NUMBER_PROCURADO){
            printf("Found it! Position: %d\n",i);
        }
        pthread_exit( (void*)pos);
    }
    pthread_exit( (void*)NULL);
}

void fillVector(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NVALORES; i++){
        vetor[i] = i+1;
    }    
}
```

Comment: `NVALORES` not defined.

Comment: It's actually defined, just didn't include it here.

Comment: It could be important if not the real problem answered by Fred.

Comment: I just said it is defined, I just didn't copy paste the whole code on here. Either way, Fred's answer solved it for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Technically, this question could be closed as off topic because it does not include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not complete because (among other things) `NVALORES` is not defined.

Comment: I edited `NVALORES` in to make it complete, what else is missing besides it ? Sorry for the newbie question, fairly new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I should be able to copy and paste your example into my editor or IDE and reproduce the problem. This should include the required header files, and I think you need a prototype of `run`.

Comment: Should I edit them in now or just leave it be since the I closed the question ?

Comment: It would be better to have it complete. I also find that `vetor` is not defined.

Comment: Okay, done, I think it's all set now, thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misusing the return value of `pthread_create`. It does not return a thread id. It returns an error code, so you're clobbering the thread id and making your `pthread_join` call invalid.

Comment: Btw, one more question, on my friends computer running Netbeans 8.1 on Ubuntu the program works and it's exactly copy pasted from mine running on Geany 1.25, any valid reason for this ? The compiler used is gcc btw. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely undefined behavior. One of the nifty things about UB is that it includes the possibility of working just fine, seg faulting, or summoning [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @FredLarson It is strange because the assertion of `threads[i]` when calling `pthread_create` could not be in another order, could it? Do you think their compilers are making the assertion in different orders? 
Since the code uses the array again (in order to join threads) I don't think the compiler could act differently. If they didn't use the array it could, in my opinion, be explained by not performing the assertion (since it would not be used), this way it is really weird. What do you think?

Comment: @XavierSilva: I am having trouble understanding your question, especially your use of the word "assertion". But what I believe is happening is that the use of `thread[i]` to receive the return value is replacing the thread id (set by `pthread_create` through the pointer in the first argument) with the error code returned by `pthread_create`. This value is then used in `pthread_join`, leading to undefined behavior because it is not a valid thread id. Nasal demons.

Comment: Basically, what I'm asking is, since he's using the `thread[i]`to receive the return value of `pthread_create` and then using it in `pthread_join`, how does the compiler still figure it out and runs the program? I don't think this can fall under the category of undefined behaviour because given that the value is used again, the compiler shouldn't be able to discard the use of the variable and work in one system but not the other.

Comment: I see no reason to expect that from the compiler. The double-edged sword of C is that it assumes the programmer knows what (s)he is doing and uses that assumption to avoid a lot of overhead. This leads to very efficient code and short compile times. It also leads to a lot of undefined behavior when that basic assumption is incorrect.